# Are any questions out of bounds?

Tags: discussion, scope, censorship

Are there [any questions that are out of bounds](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16900/colored-underwear-during-seven-clean-days) because of Tzeni'uth or just an "ick" factor that might elicit inappropriate responses (of the anti-religious sort)?

Comment: Yes, I know we've discussed CYLOR questions, controversial questions, off-topic questions, etc. I'm asking specifically about the kind of question that might make someone unfamiliar with the subject matter very uneasy about religious Judaism.

Comment: @msh210 It's amazing the typos that no one notices!

Comment: @DoubleAA, what am I, chopped liver? `:-P`

Comment: Indeed. Sorry...

Comment: SethJ Ha! Another one, and even @chopped-liver over there didn't notice it! Amazing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the [FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#notes) says:

> Please respect that in the Jewish tradition certain questions, especially certain questions relating to sexuality, are discussed only in private. Such questions will be closed or deleted at the discretion of the moderators or community.

based on discussion over at [this meta post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/123/759).

However, the lines are rather vague. I'd say if you really feel uncomfortable with a question to flag it and explain why you feel that way and perhaps the mods will delete it.

Comment: Or comment on the question or post on Meta about it, so that the community can deliberate its fitness in public.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Of course, if s/he's comfortable with that. But if you're trying to rid the site of references to women's undergarments, then switching a regular post for a meta one doesn't help much.