# Closing back-doors to deleted content for halachic reasons

Tags: support, hyperlinks, etiquette, censorship, deleted-questions

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34564/3073) has been deleted, but is still available through a click in [a comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34215/clarifying-the-prohibition-of-mishkav-zachar#comment89413_34223). Furthermore, the closed question puts attention (first link) to [content](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/34223/9) who's author [deleted it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/34223/10) on [halachic grounds](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1875/3073).

Should I delete the comment to respect the author? And this meta question too?

Comment: Only users with 10k rep (and the OP) can see a deleted post.

Answer (score 4):

Deleted posts (questions and answers) are only available to users with at least 10k rep; they're not visible to the public.  So most people following the link from the comment won't see anything.  You can see the question (even though you don't have 10k rep) because you asked it.  Nobody else under 10k can see it.

Comments are second-class citizens on Stack Exchange; their purpose is to improve the posts they're attached to and there's no expectation that they'll last forever.  You are therefore welcome to delete comments you've made at any time, and shouldn't be surprised if they get cleaned up later.  (If your deletion causes other comments to be obsolete, it's useful to flag those as obsolete so they can be cleaned up.)

So I don't see a need for you to delete your comment (and certainly not to delete this meta post), but if you feel that deleting the comment would be appropriate, feel free to do so.  And if the person whose post is being talked about asks that it be deleted, that should get more weight.

Comment: Why is the fact that I missed http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools enough to justify a down-vote?

Comment: I don't know.  I didn't downvote.

Comment: Well, I guess that either I didn't show any research effort, or my question was unclear or not useful...

Comment: Well, votes on meta are different; often they signify agreement/disagreement.  (There is no rep effect, either.)  Please don't take it personally; meta, being more discussion- and opinion-oriented, will sometimes produce puzzlements like this.