# Are all questions, answers, comments and chat room discussions expected to follow halacha?

Tags: discussion

Having looked at [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4934/old-posts-that-cite-a-since-disgraced-rabbi) and [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/using-christian-interpretations-in-answers), it seems that moderation here isn't based on politics, including the "politics" of what is kefira or not, or conspiracy, but simply the rules laid out by Stack Exchange and Mi Yodeya.

However, it seems it hasn't been asked if all posts are expected to follow halacha, especially the laws of Lashon Hara.

If someone speaks lashon hara, or posits rechulit, embarrasses a fellow user, uses foul language, disparages Hashem, the Torah or Chazal, is untznius, or any other halachic breaches - should it be flagged? If so, what halachic standard should be used?

Comment: regarding modesty, see https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/123/759 and those linked thereto

Comment: re lashon hara https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5254/759

Comment: re heresy https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2103/759

Answer (score 4):

This community is bound to follow the rules of the Stack Exchange network and the community-specific policies of Mi Yodeya. It is not, by constitution, bound to follow Halacha. That said, as community-specific policies are decided through community deliberation here in Meta, and as most community members (the core expert population [who](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) "base their lives on Jewish law and tradition") consider Halacha binding on themselves personally, Halacha-based arguments for particular policies are likely to carry particular weight.

The above is my description of the meta-policy status quo, as I understand it. In theory, someone could write an alternative answer to this question advocating that all policies here adhere to Halachic standards as set out in Code C or as determined by Posek P, and if that answer achieved sufficient community consensus, it could change the meta-policy and presumably several specific policies. In my opinion, that would be a bad idea, since it would spark debate that would go way far afield before it could practically help set any policy here.

If you would like the community to set policies on any of the specific issues you list, I recommend posting a question here on that issue in particular, or possibly bumping one of the existing Q&A posts on these topics, such as those linked in the comments on this question.